# How can I stop my counter from going to 48 from 0 after it records x for look up in a character array?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, increment

Below I have included a snippet of my decrypt method using a polybius square. I am wanting to take the first two user inputs and turn them into coordinates to look up what letter in the square matches the input numbers. My code works for the x value and then assigns the y as 48. i need help finding to incriment between x and y without changing y to 48.

```
public string DecryptMessage(string userInput)
    {
        string outputMessage = string.Empty;

        char[,] alphaValues = new char[5, 5] {
            {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'},
            {'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K'},
            {'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'},
            {'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U'},
            {'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'},
        };

        char[] userInputArray = userInput.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < userInputArray.Length; i++)
            {
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(userInputArray[i]); i++;
            //after this point i somehow changes from 0 to 48 with the incriment
            //if i get this fixed the decrypt will work, still trying to figure this out

                int y = Convert.ToInt32(userInputArray[i]);


                char letterToReturn = alphaValues[x, y];


                string outputLetter = letterToReturn.ToString();
                outputMessage += outputLetter;

            }
        return outputMessage;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you do that `i++;` after `int x = Convert.ToInt32(userInputArray[i]); `. This is a bad decision

Comment: Are you just trying to make the index for y just i + 1?

Comment: You have a `i++` increment after `x` which will hold your index.  Also, wouldn't you want a `foreach` for the user input?

Comment: Is the ciphertext just a string of numbers?

Comment: Is `userInputArray` a list of x-y pairs as in [x1, y1, x2, y2,... xn, yn]?

Comment: What do you do with `J`? You just can't use that letter?

Comment: @MegaTron the i++ is supposed to incriment i from the 0 position to the 1 position in the user input array. so i want x to equal the first value and y to equal the second value so that i can make it into an x and y pairing to look up the letter value of the two numbers and add that to the output string.

Comment: @itsme86 yes the cipher text is a string of numbers. if the user enters 00 it should return A, i want to convert the user input into coordinates 2 at a time basically

Comment: Ok then create a new variable for that. Do not increase loop variable manually in for!

Comment: @juharr yes it is supposed to be a list of x y pairs but i am having trouble getting it to act that way

Comment: char[] userInputArray = userInput.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < userInputArray.Length; i++)
            {
                int index = i;
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(userInputArray[index]);
                index++;
                if (index < userInputArray.Length)
                    index = 0;
                int y = Convert.ToInt32(userInputArray[index]);
                char letterToReturn = alphaValues[ x % 5, y % 5];
                string outputLetter = letterToReturn.ToString();
                outputMessage += outputLetter;

            }

Comment: so the above is what i have now and i am still getting index out of range exception

Comment: @AleahStrength Don't put code into a comment.  Instead edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're converting the character representation of the digit to a integer, which is going to be the numeric value that represents that character rather than the digit you're looking for.

Try this:

```
...
int x = userInputArray[i++] - '0';
int y = userInputArray[i] - '0';
char letterToReturn = alphaValues[x, y];
...
```

Since '0' through '9' are represented by 48 through 57, subtracting '0' from the character effectively turns the digit character into the actual number.

'0' is 48, '1' is 49, and so on all the way up to '9' being 57, so '1' - '0' is 49 - 48 or just 1. '9' - '0' is 57 - 48 or just 9.

Of course this little trick depends on the character set being used, but it works for ASCII and unicode.

Comment: This is exactly the problem i was trying to solve! thank you! it now works correctly!